# Lower bound on the number of objects in the universe

Tags: it.information-theory, shannon-entropy, prefix-free-code

From Cover & Thomas' *Elements of Information Theory*:

> Player A chooses some object in the universe,
>   and player B attempts to identify the object with a series of yes–no
>   questions. Suppose that player B is clever enough to use the code
>   achieving the minimal expected length with respect to player A’s
>   distribution. We observe that player B requires an average of 38.5
>   questions to determine the object. Find a rough lower bound to the
>   number of objects in the universe.

The solution in the solutions manuals is $37.5 = L^* - 1 < H(X) \leq log|\chi|$.

Why can we be sure that the difference between the minimum expected length and $1$ is smaller than the entropy?

Answer (score 3):

Because an optimal prefix free code, e.g. a Huffman code, can be shown to be within one bit of source entropy. This is certainly in Cover and Thomas, I am pretty sure.